# Node: Express: How to handle application/octet-stream;charset=;UTF-8 response?

Tags: node.js, express, utf-8, content-type, unirest

I have a node-express application.
There, I'm trying to make a call to an API which is responding an raw xlsx object as

> 'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream;charset=;UTF-8'

Code how I'm calling the API:

```
var unirest = require("unirest");

var reqClient = unirest("POST", "https://api.application.com/getExcel");
reqClient.headers({ "Authorization": "Bearer " + req.session.passport.user.token, 
"content-type": req.headers['content-type'], "application/json"});
reqClient.type("json");
reqClient.send(JSON.stringify(requestbody));
reqClient.end(function(res) {
if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
console.log(res.body);
});
```

Now 2 things I'm trying to do actually with this data.

1. Write that into an excel file.
   Below is the code how I'm trying it:

```
    let data = res.body // res is the response coming from the API
    let buf = Buffer.from(data);
    excelfile = fs.createWriteStream("result.xlsx");
    excelfile.write(buf);
    excelfile.end();
```

2. Trying to send it to **UI** where the excelfile will get created.
   Below is my code for that:

```
    let data = res.body // res is the response coming from the API
    let buf = Buffer.from(data);
    response.write(buf); //response is the response to the request to ui
    response.end();
```

So in both the cases the file is coming corrupted.

But the API response is prefect because, when it's directly getting consumed by the **UI**, xlsx file is generating properly.

Comment: 1. Try `fs.writeFile("result.xlsx", buf, "binary", (err) =>{});`

Comment: Please show how are you calling the API. It seems you're using `axios` or similar.

Comment: @KevinHernandez still getting error while trying to open the file. "We found a problem with some content in 'result.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

Comment: It's an easy fix, update the code with the API request.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande i have update the API calling code
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59199767/revisions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with binary data, you have to set the encoding to `null`

```
reqClient.encoding(null)
```

```js
reqClient.encoding(null)
reqClient.end(function(res) {
    if (res.error) {
       return response.status(500).send('error');
    }

    // res.body is now a buffer
    response.write(res.body);
    response.end();
});
```

Otherwise, the data is converted to `UTF-8` and you can't convert from `UTF-8` back to binary and get the same data, which is what you were doing:

```
Buffer.from(res.body)
```

The recommended approach is to use streams directly, I don't see a way of doing this in a simple way in  `unirest`, I recommend using `request` or `got`, so you can `.pipe` directly to a file or express `res`